# Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Developer Edition Data Tuning Advisor tool

Tags: sql-server-2008, installation

I have Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Developer Edition installed on my machine which has Win7 64 bit OS. 
I am not able see Data Tuning Advisor tool in my SSMS. Before this installation my machine already had SQL server 2008 R2 express edition. I upgraded shared components as well but no success.

One thing I noticed while installing developer edition is that there was no option to choose "Management tools - Complete" it was only "Management tools - Basic". Is this an issue?

Can anybody help me getting this tool?

Comment: I think what Aaron said is correct. Just to ask, though, I assume you don't see an item for DTA in the Start Menu group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to completely uninstall the client tools portion of your Express instance first, since side-by-side installations of Management Studio Express and Management Studio are not supported - there is no direct upgrade path, it's either one or the other.